# How can I read data from COM object (an activex server) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, pointers, activex, pass-by-reference, com-object

I am trying to connect a simulator to the MATLAB. The simulator program exposes a COM object interface.

I have connected to the COM object by the following command and can perform most of it methods:

```
h=actxserver(ProgID)
```

But some of its methods need passing of a `Variant*` type as output.

Here is the signature of one of the methods indicated by "invoke" method:

```
ReadOutputImage=Variant(Pointer) ReadOutputImage(handle, int32, int32, `ImageDataTypeConstants, Variant(Pointer))`
```

I have called this method with several syntax's, but none of them work:

```
a=uint8([0])   %means unsigned integer array with 1 member

h.ReadOutputImage(0,1,2,a)  % 0 ,1 ,2 are contants pointing to the position, number of elements to read and size of elemnts while 2 shows Byte element (VT_UI2 COM type).
```

Other syntax's that I have tried and has no result are: using `uint16`, `uint32`, `int8`, `int16`, `int32` for all of the followings:

```
logical types (like a=[false]), 
cell arrays (like a={uint8([0])} )
empty cell array {}
empty array []
empty sring ''
```

I have used libpointer as well:

```
a=libpointer;
also a=libpointer('uint8Ptr',0)
also a=libpointer('bool',false)
also a=libpointer('bool',[0])
```

The problem is that I am not sure about the following items:

1. What is the similar type of " Variant(Pointer) " in MATLAB?
2. What is the method of passing a variable as output to a COM method in MATLAB?
3. Is it even possible to get a value from a COM object method result as a pointer in MATLAB?

To find how the data appears in other clients, I have imported the same dll file into Delphi and the signature of the type library for the above method is like this:

```
procedure ReadOutputImage(StartIndex: Integer; ElementsToRead: Integer; 
                          DataType: ImageDataTypeConstants; var pData: OleVariant);
```

---

Yes Siemens has provided a guide for this com server (prosim) and based on such documentation I have connected and performed most of its methods. But the methods which read I/o data are not working. In documentation the method signature is specified as follows: (in VB)

```
STDMETHOD(CS7Prosim::ReadOutputImage)(long startindex,long elementstoread, imagedatatypeconstants DtaType, VARIANT* pData)
```

What about your application, was it working? Did it contains variant pointers as the returning argument? Did you have simillar methods in that application?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any documentation you can point to for the sim you're trying to interface with?  My only experience with this sort of functionality in Matlab was with a confocal imaging program called Imaris and they provided some good information on how to interact with their program once you established the COM object, which it appears you can do.

Comment: Yes Siemens has provided a guide for this com server (prosim) and based on such documentation I have connected and performed most of its methods. But the methods which read I/o data are not working. In documentation the method signature is specified as follows: (in VB)

STDMETHOD(CS7Prosim::ReadOutputImage)(long startindex,long elementstoread, imagedatatypeconstants DtaType, VARIANT* pData)
What about your application, was it working? Did it contains variant pointers as the returning argument? Did you have simillar methods in that application?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I can help with #2 in your question.  I just worked through this myself. Basically, any pass by reference to COM object you to access after it is modified, Matlab just spits back as an output.

```
[var1 a]=thisObject.DB.Execute(queryString,a)
```

See [here](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/matlab_external/ch07cl12.html#com_method_enumeration)
"The syntax shown here shows a server function being called by the MATLAB client. The function's return value is shown as retval. The function's output arguments `(out1, out2, ...)` follow this:

```
[retval out1 out2 ...] = handle.functionname(in1, in2, ...);
```

MATLAB makes use of the pass by reference capabilities in COM to implement this feature. Note that pass by reference is a COM feature. It is not available in MATLAB at this time."