# Get multiple outputs from a COM object in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, com

I'm trying to read some data from CST Microwave Studio in MATLAB using CST's COM objects.

First, I got the project COM object's reference by executing

```matlab
hApp = actxserver(ProgID);
hProj = hApp.OpenFile(ProjectFile);
```

At this point normally COM server returns signatures of all available methods of the COM-object by executing

```matlab
MethSig = invoke(hProj);
```

It works well in e.g. MS Office programs, but it returns nothing for CST COM-objects... (Is it something to do with IDispatch interface not implemented in CST?)

Anyway, it is possible to call CST COM-object's methods by using the following syntax (taking the `MethodName` and its arguments from the CST VBS documentation):

```matlab
Out1 = hProj.invoke(MethodName, In1, In2, ...)
```

However, some methods return several output arguments, e.g. (again, from CST VBS documentation):

```vb
GetParameterCombination( string  resultID, variant parameterNames, variant  parameterValues  ) bool
```

where `resultID` is the input argument, and `parameterNames` and `parameterValues` are output arguments.
In a such case in other COM-enabled apps (like MS Office) MATLAB takes care of the output parameters splitting, and the following syntax would work:

```matlab
[Out1, Out2, ...] = hWorkSheet.invoke(MethodName, In1, In2, ...);
% or even using dot-notation:
[Out1, Out2, ...] = hWorkSheet.MethodName(In1, In2, ...);
```

However, it doesn't work with CST:

```matlab
[RetVal, parameterNames, parameterValues] = hProj.invoke('GetParameterCombination', '3D:RunID:1');
Error using Interface.CSTStudio_Application.Active3D/invoke
Error: Missing a required parameter
```

I have tried to pass the output arguments in similar ways as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848915/how-can-i-read-data-from-com-object-an-activex-server-in-matlab) question, without any success, always getting the error:

```
Error using Interface.CSTStudio_Application.Active3D/invoke
Error: Type mismatch, argument 2
```

Is there any way to get all output variables from a COM-object in this case?
A some sort of Java wrapper perhaps?

Thanks.

Comment: The question is still actual... Nobody has any idea?

Comment: I don't know if that makes a difference but the signature for `GetParameterCombination` seems to have 3 parameters as input (even if 2 of them are also outputs). In your line `[RetVal, parameterNames, parameterValues] = hProj.invoke('GetParameterCombination', '3D:RunID:1');` shouldn't you send 2 more parameters ? Even if they won't actually hold the return values in Matlab, the COM server might need them to perform appropriately (also the error message `Missing a required parameter` seems to indicates it is expecting more inputs ...)

Comment: @Hoki, Thanks for the comment. As I mentioned at the end of the question, I have tried to pass additional arguments (and also gave a link to the thread, where the author tried similar things), but I always get error `Error: Type mismatch, argument 2` ...

Comment: Could you show the full line which produced this error ? (so we can see what type were the arguments sent in)

Comment: also, could this Matlab toolbox help you : [A Matlab to CST Interface](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/67731-hgiddenss-cst_app) ?

Comment: @Hoki, I have tried several ways, e.g. 1) `[RetVal, parameterNames, parameterValues] = hProj.invoke('GetParameterCombination', '3D:RunID:1');`, 2) `parameterNames = {};  parameterValues = [];  RetVal = hProj.invoke('GetParameterCombination', '3D:RunID:1', parameterNames, parameterValues);`, 3) `parameterNames = cell(0,0);`, 4) also using Matlab's `libpointer` as `parameterNames = libpointer('stringPtrPtr');` and other data types. All of these gives the same error `Error: Type mismatch, argument 2`...

Comment: As for the Matlab to CST interface you refer to, yes, I saw it before, and it is a great peace of work, but the author doesn't use APIs with several output arguments, so it dosn't help with my problem... For now I use a work-around: from Matlab I write VBA macro which runs within CST and saves output data to a text file, which I then read in Matlab. But I'm still looking for a better solution...